# How to add Windows to boot menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, bootloader

I have 2 hard drives, one with Windows and one with Ubuntu.

How can I easily add Windows to the boot menu? I've installed GRUB customizer; can it be done with that program?

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file by:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

add an entry like:

```
menuentry 'Windows 7′ {
set root='(hd0,msdos2)’
chainloader +1
}
```

Since you have two drives, you should also modify the location of Windows in the above script accordingly.

After that run:

```
sudo update-grub
```